# Input Variables not updating on Flows

Tags: visual-workflow

For some of my flows when I add an input variable it is not appearing as an available input in either debugging or the subflow action unless I save it as a new flow entirely (different API name). When I have raised this to support as we are not premier they have told me to go pound sand so I just want to make sure I'm not doing anything wrong.

[Example Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R93468TCvPY)

Comment: shot in dark - try updating the api version of the flow to 51

Comment: @cropredy same deal unless I save as an entirely new API name the list of available inputs don't change

Answer (score 0):

try cloning from the Flow version where all the prior functionalities were working and then add new elements because sometimes cloning the same flawed flow might not give the required result.

Comment: if I save as a new API Name entirely it works but all previous versions of the flow have the same issue